# How To add Mapping Configuration in Model For column like Name1 Map to Name In Cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have need to mapping configuration in model to map field like Name1 to Name.

I have tried this but it is not working

```
$virtualFields = array('Name1' => 'Name');
```

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 3 you need to use [accessors](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators) for virtual fields. So you need to add an accessor to the relevant entity. For example:-

```
class User extends Entity
{

    protected function _getName1()
    {
        return $this->_properties['name'];
    }

}
```

> Accessors use the convention of _get followed by the CamelCased version of the field name.

So with this example the `name1` property is now part of the entity:-

```
<?= $user->name1 ?>
```

Comment: can you explain in detail please

Comment: I've added some more details to my answer. I'd recommend following the link in my answer and reading the docs on accessors if you are not familiar with them as the official documentation explains these in a lot of detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can try thin in CAKEPHP 3

```
$this->ModelName->find()->select(['alias_nmae'=>'actual_name'])
```